Itemize inside scontents produces error
Background
The software xournal++ can use latex to visualize content. For that it uses a template standalone file and fills in user input into an scontents environment. I provide here their reduced template file that still produces the error as a mwe (or minimal failing example?).
The Problem
I would like to use an itemize environment inside scontents. Additionally, I guess the template computes the height of the stored content to check whether there is a problem. However, I get the following error:
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.24 ...toheight{\pheight}{\getstored[1]{preview}}

Below my minimal example that produces the error, and at the end of the post the complete log. If I do not use an itemize environment, I do not get an error.
\documentclass[varwidth=0.999\maxdimen, crop, border=5pt]{standalone}

\newcommand*{\setTextWidthReference}{%
    \setlength{\textwidth}{345.0pt}% Same value when you use 'varwidth=true'.
    \setlength{\linewidth}{\textwidth}%
    \setlength{\columnwidth}{\textwidth}%
}

% for storing in memory verbatim content to be reused later
\usepackage{scontents}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newlength{\pheight}

% User input
\begin{scontents}[store-env=preview]
\begin{itemize}
    \item Text
\end{itemize}
\end{scontents}

\begin{document}
    \setTextWidthReference
    % Check if the formula is empty
    \settoheight{\pheight}{\getstored[1]{preview}}%

    \ifthenelse{\pheight=0}{\GenericError{}{blank}{}{}}
    
    \getstored[1]{preview}
\end{document}

The log file (with package versions): https://pastebin.com/raw/TKu9DvEC

The error has nothing to do with scontents.
Minimal example:
\documentclass{article}
\newlength{\pheight}

\begin{document}

\settoheight{\pheight}{\begin{itemize}\item Text\end{itemize}}

\end{document}

Console output:
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.6 ...ht}{\begin{itemize}\item Text\end{itemize}}

The text for \settoheight should not have paragraphs.
\documentclass[varwidth=0.999\maxdimen, crop, border=5pt]{standalone}

\newcommand*{\setTextWidthReference}{%
    \setlength{\textwidth}{345.0pt}% Same value when you use 'varwidth=true'.
    \setlength{\linewidth}{\textwidth}%
    \setlength{\columnwidth}{\textwidth}%
}

% for storing in memory verbatim content to be reused later
\usepackage{scontents}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newlength{\pheight}

% User input
\begin{scontents}[store-env=preview]
\begin{itemize}
    \item Text
\end{itemize}
\end{scontents}

\begin{document}
    \setTextWidthReference
    % Check if the formula is empty
    \settoheight{\pheight}{\begin{varwidth}{\maxdimen}\getstored[1]{preview}\end{varwidth}}%
    \ifthenelse{\pheight=0}{\GenericError{}{blank}{}{}}
    \getstored[1]{preview}
\end{document}

I'm not sure what the use of this would be, though.
